# Python/Django: Is model deletable

Tags: python, django

I have model that can be protected by other model's foreign key field. Is there any easy way of determining if proteced model instance can be deleted from DB withaout actually being deleted? Only idea that comes to my mind is using transactions/rollbacks, but it seems ugly. Is there any better solution?

Comment: No, since it's not a feature the underlying DBs support.

Comment: UNLESS you check for EVERY possibly related table.